# Как написать на Python запросы из приложения на андроид?

Tags: android, python, android-studio

Есть приложение на андроид и в нем есть форма входа, которая должна использовать пароли и логины для аутентификации пользователя, логины и пароли висят на сервере, и я так понял что файл на python это как мост между приложением и бд где есть эти пароли и логины. Я так понимаю что нужно как-то прописать запросы на подключение к бд и сверку паролей и логинов из бд с введенными в проге. Я не сильно шарю в этом вопросе я здесь новичок и буду благодарен за любые советы и помощь.

Comment: Готовыми решениями воспользуйтесь. [Why shouldn't we roll our own?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/438) Какими именно, зависит от того, что вы на сервере используете, к примеру, `django.contrib.auth`